# How to fully implement server-sent events for message polling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, polling, server-sent-events

I am trying to communicate with a server using an API.

to make it easier I wrote a script that will communicate the API using a php script.

My goal is to make a query to the API every second to see if there is new message in their queue.

I was advised to use [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) method and have the server send a respond to the client only when it has something new.

Here is my php script

```
<?php

    // Register autoloader function
    spl_autoload_register('apiAutoloader');
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");

    $config = array('host' => 'server:IP',              //REQUIRED - Server Name
                    'port' => 8018,                     //REQUIRED - Server Port
                    'userID' => 'user',                 //REQUIRED - UserID to login with
                    'password' => '123456',             //REQUIRED - password for the UserID to login with
                    );

    try {

        //create a new instance of icws
        $icws = new API\ICWS($config); 

        //create a new session
        $icws->createSession(true);     

        while(1){

            $result = $icws->processMessage();
            echo json_encode($result);  

            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);

        }

    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    function apiAutoloader($className)
    {
        $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
        $fileName  = '';
        $namespace = '';

        if ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\')) 
        {
            $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
            $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
            $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }

        $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

        $toLoad = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$fileName;

        if (is_file($toLoad) === true)
        {
            include $toLoad;
        }
    }
?>
```

When a user visit my page this is the code the I run

```
<script>

    $(function(){

        function isset(a, b){

            if(typeof a !== "undefined" && a){
                return a
            }

            return b;
        }


        var evtSource = new EventSource("poll.php");

        evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {

            $.each(e.data.calls, function(i, item){

                $.each(item, function(z, c){

                    var interactionId = isset(c.interactionId, 0);
                    var Eic_CallDirection = isset(c.Eic_CallDirection, '');
                    var Eic_State = isset(c.Eic_State, '');
                    var AccoRDI_mid = isset(c.AccoRDI_mid, '');
                    var Eic_RemoteAddress = isset(c.Eic_RemoteAddress, '');

                    if(Eic_State == '' || Eic_CallDirection == ''){
                        return;
                    }

                    //incoming call that is not answered
                    if( Eic_CallDirection == 'I' && Eic_State == 'A'){
                        console.log('Incomming Call From ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + ' MID: ' + AccoRDI_mid );
                        return;
                    }

                    //on hold
                    if( Eic_State == 'H'){
                        console.log('Phone number ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + ' is on hold' );
                        return;
                    }

                    //voicemail
                    if( Eic_State == 'M'){
                        console.log('Phone number ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + ' is on leaving a voicemail' );
                        return;
                    }

                    //connected call
                    if(Eic_State == 'C'){
                        console.log('Live Call With ' + Eic_RemoteAddress );
                        return;
                    }

                    //Dialling call
                    if(Eic_State == 'O'){
                        console.log('Dialling ' + Eic_RemoteAddress );
                        return;
                    }

                    //Dialling call
                    if(Eic_State == 'R'){
                        console.log('Outbound call is rining and waiting for answer ' );
                        return;
                    }

                    //Call Disconnected
                    if(Eic_State == 'I' || Eic_State == 'E' ){
                        console.log('Hungup with ' + Eic_RemoteAddress );
                        return;
                    }

                });
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

my code above is not working.

I don't get anything in my console. but this error `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at /icws/poll.php`

How can I get it to work?
Is the way I implemented by PHP script correct?

Comment: Try `ob_end_flush()` instead. It looks like there is a problem with buffering. Apache / Nginx?

Comment: still get an error `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at /icws/poll.php.`

Comment: What does icws->processMessage();  returns ?

Comment: @Zalaboza it returns an array that looks like this `{"calls":[[{"interactionId":"2002927194","account_id":"9985","mid":"","Eic_CallDirection":"I","Eic_RemoteAddress":"5467893548","Eic_LocalAddress":"1062","Eic_State":"O"}]],"status":[{"statusId":"Available","userId":"user","loggedIn":true}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the status code on the browser request for you event source php file ? Try to use firebug to make sure its not 404.

Also regarding php code.

According to Mozilla source you included in your question. 
Proper response from server should be  named and separated by newlines

```
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");     
while (1) {     
  echo "event: ping\n"; //event name
  echo 'data: '.json(); //event data
  Echo "\n\n"; //required  

  ob_flush(); flush(); sleep(1);    
 }
```

Event example

```
event: userconnect
data: {"username": "bobby", "time": "02:33:48"} 

event: usermessage
data: {"username": "bobby", "time": "02:34:11", "text": "Hi everyone."}
```

Comment: still now working. here is the error now `The connection to https://accordi.rdimarketing.com/icws/poll.php was interrupted while the page was loading.`

Comment: Try to open the page directly and wait for couple mins

Comment: I accepted your answer after I corrected the issue. I will post an answer with everything I have done to help the next guy :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I added a listener event like so

```
        var evtSource = new EventSource("poll.php");

        evtSource.addEventListener("ping", function(e) {

          var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
          processMessages(obj);

        }, false);
```

and I wrote my `processMessages` function like so

```
        function processMessages(obj) {

            $.each(obj.calls, function(i, item){

                $.each(item, function(z, c){

                    var interactionId = isset(c.interactionId, 0);
                    var Eic_CallDirection = isset(c.Eic_CallDirection, '');
                    var Eic_State = isset(c.Eic_State, '');
                    var mid = isset(c.mid, '');
                    var account_id = isset(c.account_id, '');
                    var Eic_RemoteAddress = isset(c.Eic_RemoteAddress, '');

                    if(Eic_State == '' || Eic_CallDirection == ''){
                        return;
                    }

                    //incoming call that is not answered
                    if( Eic_CallDirection == 'I' && Eic_State == 'A'){
                    var msg = '';
                        if(mid != ''){
                            msg = ' MID: ' + mid;
                        }

                        if(account_id != ''){
                            msg = ' Account ID: ' + account_id;
                        }
                        console.log('Incomming Call From ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + msg );
                        return;
                    }

                    //on hold
                    if( Eic_State == 'H'){
                        console.log('Phone number ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + ' is on hold' );
                        return;
                    }

                    //voicemail
                    if( Eic_State == 'M'){
                        console.log('Phone number ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + ' is on leaving a voicemail' );
                        return;
                    }

                    //connected call
                    if(Eic_State == 'C'){
                        console.log('Live Call With ' + Eic_RemoteAddress );
                        return;
                    }

                    //Dialling call
                    if(Eic_State == 'O' && Eic_CallDirection = 'O'){
                        console.log('Dialling ' + Eic_RemoteAddress );
                        return;
                    }

                    //Dialling call
                    if(Eic_State == 'R'){
                        console.log('Outbound call is rining and waiting for answer ' );
                        return;
                    }

                    //Call Disconnected
                    if(Eic_State == 'I' || Eic_State == 'E' ){
                        console.log('Hungup with ' + Eic_RemoteAddress );
                        return;
                    }

                });
            });
        }
```

and my PHP code looks like this

```
    while(1){

        $result = array('test' => 'This is a test records');
        echo 'event: ping' . "\n";
        echo 'data: ' . json_encode($result) . "\n";    
        echo "\n"; //required  

        ob_flush(); flush(); sleep(1);   

    }
```

Few things to point out in the PHP. It is IMPORTANT to have `\n`after each line and one more at the very end. also it is important to look for the keyword `ping` which is located in my PHP code and in the listener event in my javascript code. if you change it you must change it in 2 places.

I hope this helps someone :)